# Как сделать конвертор txt в html текст

Tags: python, tkinter

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
def clicked():
    text = txt.get('1.0',tkinter.END)
    print(text)
    f = open('text.txt', 'w',encoding='utf-8')
    f.write(text)
window = Tk()
window.title("Добро пожаловать в приложение LuckyWindow")
window.geometry('1920x1080')
lbl = Label(window, text="Введите text")
lbl.grid(column=0, row=0)
txt = Text(window, width=100)
txt.grid(column=1, row=0)
btn = Button(window, text="Начать!", command=clicked)
btn.grid(column=5, row=10)
window.mainloop()
```

Пишу что то вроде бота для отправки писем. Мне необходимо написать конвертор кода из txt в html.
Как делает это сайт. https://ru.texthandler.com/text-tools/text-to-html/
Может существует готовая библиотека или другое решение.

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно сначала экранировать все символы типа `<`, `>` (и другие, которые имеют специальное значение в html), потом заменить переносы строк на тег `<br />`.

Первое делается с помощью функции [`escape`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.html#html.escape) из модуля `html`, второе - просто с помощью метода replace. Пример:

```
text = "<<<Привет!\n>>>Пока!"
print(html.escape(text).replace("\n", "<br />"))
```

Вывод:

```
&lt;&lt;&lt;Привет!<br />&gt;&gt;&gt;Пока!
```

Ниже можно просмотреть отображение полученного html (нужно нажать на "Выполнить код"):

```html
&lt;&lt;&lt;Привет!<br />&gt;&gt;&gt;Пока!
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Очень помогло!